# Mysql Function returns Null always

Tags: mysql, function

I have a function in mysql like below:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost FUNCTION fnGetDropDownValue(
    itemValue varchar(300), 
    DropDownId int, 
    CId int
) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE listId int;
    SELECT ListID into listId FROM DropDownListValues WHERE LOWER(ListValue) = LOWER(itemValue) AND DropDownListID = DropDownId AND (ClientId = 0 OR ClientId = CId);
    RETURN listId;
END$$
```

But it always returns Null values when I use 
`SELECT fnGetDropDownValue('General', 24, 18);`
I don't know what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: Have you checked your error log? What errors do you get? What steps have you taken to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you tried your query direct in sheel? Does it return it value?

Comment: I used to check executing select query in a separate window and it gives result

Comment: What happens if you replace the select query in the function with a simple `SELECT 5 INTO listId`?  Does it still give you NULL?

Comment: Thanks for the help Alanyst i noticed in windows it as case insensitive. I changed variable listId to listId1 and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having the case sensitive issue with mysql columns I used to have variable names to start with _ to avoid it messing with column names. Now the stored procedure looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE DEFINER=root@localhost FUNCTION fnGetDropDownValue(
    itemValue varchar(300), 
    DropDownId int, 
    CId int
) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _listId int;
    SELECT ListID into _listId FROM DropDownListValues WHERE LOWER(ListValue) = LOWER(itemValue) 
        AND DropDownListID = DropDownId AND (ClientId = 0 OR ClientId = CId);
    RETURN _listId;
END$$
```

This way it will work on any platform and it may be useful for others.